# Calculate sum and cumul by age group and by date (but people changes age group as time passes)

Tags: sql, postgresql, cartesian-product

**DBMS** : postgreSQL

**my problem** :
In my database I have a `person` table with id and birth date, an `events` table that links a person, an event (`id_event`) and a date, an `age` table used for grouping ages. In the real database the `person` table is about 40 millions obs, and `events` 3 times bigger.

I need to produce a report (sum and cumul of X events) by age (`age_group`) and date (`event_date`). There isn't any problem to count the number of events by date. The problem lies with the cumul : contrary to other variables (sex for example), a person grow older and changes age group
as time passes, so for a given age group the cumul can increase then decrease. I want that the event's cumul, on every date in my report,  uses the age of the persons on these dates.

Example of my inputs and desired output

[image: Example of my inputs and desired output]

The only way I found is to do a **Cartesian product** on the tables `person` and the dates `v_dates`, so it's easy to follow an event and make it change `age_group`. The code below uses this method.
BUT I can't use a cartesian product on my real data (makes a table way too big) and I need to use another method.

**reproductible example**
In this simplified example I want to produce a report by month from 2020-07-01 to 2022-07-01 (view `v_dates`). In reality I need to produce the same report by day but the logic remains the same.

### My inputs

```sql
/* create table person*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS person;
CREATE TABLE person 
(
    person_id varchar(1), 
    person_birth_date date 
);
INSERT INTO person 
VALUES ('A', '2017-01-01'), 
       ('B', '2016-07-01');
```

| person_id | person_birth_date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2000-10-01 |
| B | 2010-02-01 |

```sql
/* create table events*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events;
CREATE TABLE events 
(
    person_id   varchar(1), 
    event_id integer, 
    event_date date
);
INSERT INTO events 
VALUES ('A', 1, '2020-07-01'), 
       ('A', 2, '2021-07-01'), 
       ('B', 1, '2021-01-01'), 
       ('B', 2, '2022-01-01');
```

| person_id | event_id | event_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| A | 2 | 2021-01-01 |
| B | 1 | 2020-07-01 |
| B | 2 | 2021-01-01 |

```sql
/* create table age*/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS age;
CREATE TABLE age 
(
    age integer, 
    age_group varchar(8)
);
INSERT INTO age 
VALUES (0,'[0-4]'), 
       (1,'[0-4]'), 
       (2,'[0-4]'), 
       (3,'[0-4]'), 
       (4,'[0-4]'), 
       (5,'[5-9]'), 
       (6,'[5-9]'), 
       (7,'[5-9]'), 
       (8,'[5-9]'), 
       (9,'[5-9]');

/* create view dates : contains monthly dates from 2020-07-01 to 2022-07-01*/
CREATE or replace view v_dates AS 
    SELECT GENERATE_SERIES('2020-07-01'::date, '2022-07-01'::date, '6 month')::date as event_date;
```

| age | age_group |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | [0-4] |
| 1 | [0-4] |
|  |  |
| 5 | [5-9] |

### My current method using a cartesian product

1. `CROSS JOIN` `person` * `v_dates`
   with a `LEFT JOIN` to get info from table events
   with a `LEFT JOIN` to get age_group from table age

```
CREATE or replace view v_person_event AS
  SELECT 
      pdev.person_id, 
      pdev.event_date, 
      pdev.age, 
      ag.age_group, 
      pdev.event1, 
      pdev.event2
  FROM 
  (
      SELECT  pd.person_id,
              pd.event_date, 
              date_part('year', age(pd.event_date::TIMESTAMP, pd.person_birth_date::TIMESTAMP)) as age,
              CASE WHEN ev.event_id = 1 THEN 1 else 0 END as event1,
              CASE WHEN ev.event_id = 2 THEN 1 else 0 END as event2
      FROM 
      (
            SELECT * 
            FROM person 
            CROSS JOIN v_dates
      ) pd
      LEFT JOIN events ev 
      on pd.person_id = ev.person_id 
      and pd.event_date = ev.event_date
  ) pdev
  Left JOIN age as ag on pdev.age = ag.age
  ORDER by pdev.person_id, pdev.event_date;
```

2. add columns `event1_cum` and `event2_cum`

```sql
CREATE or replace view v_person_event_cum AS
  SELECT *,
      SUM(event1) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY event_date) event1_cum,
      SUM(event2) OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY event_date) event2_cum
  FROM v_person_event;
SELECT * FROM v_person_event_cum;
```

| person_id | event_date | age | age_group | event1 | event2 | event1_cum | event2_cum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-07-01 | 3 | [0-4] | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 2021-01-01 | 4 | [0-4] | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 2021-07-01 | 4 | [0-4] | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2022-01-01 | 5 | [5-9] | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 2022-07-01 | 5 | [5-9] | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2020-07-01 | 4 | [0-4] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| B | 2021-01-01 | 4 | [0-4] | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2021-07-01 | 5 | [5-9] | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| B | 2022-01-01 | 5 | [5-9] | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2022-07-01 | 6 | [5-9] | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

3. desired output : create a report grouped by variables `age_group` and `event_date`

```sql
SELECT
    age_group,
    event_date, 
    SUM(event1) as event1, 
    SUM(event2) as event2, 
    SUM(event1_cum) as event1_cum, 
    SUM(event2_cum) as event2_cum
FROM v_person_event_cum 
GROUP BY age_group, event_date
ORDER BY age_group, event_date;
```

| age_group | event_date | event1 | event2 | event1_cum | event2_cum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [0-4] | `2020-07-01` | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| [0-4] | `2021-01-01` | 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| [0-4] | `2021-07-01` | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| [5-9] | `2021-07-01` | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| [5-9] | `2022-01-01` | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

This is why this is not an ordinary cumul : for the `age_group` [0-4],  `event1_cum` goes from 2 at '2021-01-01' to 1 at '2021-07-01' because A was in [0-4] at the time of the event 1, still in [0-4] at '2021-01-01' but in [5-9] at 2021-07-01

When we read the report:

- the 2021-01-01,  there was 2 person between 0 and 4 (at that date) who had event1 and 0 person who had event2.
- the 2021-07-01, there was 1 person between 0 and 4 who had event1 and 1 person who had event2.

I can't get a solution to this problem without using a cartesian Product...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: As per the [*How to ask* guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please [**do not** post images of code, data, error message, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy or type the text into your question, [formatted as code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361#251362). Reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs; things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please create an online [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (for example at https://www.db-fiddle.com/) and put its link along with the corresponding desired output in your question. Also, why does the current desired output have columns event _1 and event_2? What are you actually trying to find out?

Comment: it's https://www.db-fiddle.com (a tiny amount of searching would have let you figure that out). There's also http://sqlfiddle.com but it's often down.

Comment: There is actually a small mistake, the patient B has successively 4, 4, 5, 5, 6 years old and not 4, 4, 5, 6, 6 years old. OK I'll make an online example as soon as I can. I have multiple medical examinations/reports in my database with "successive events" that I need to report, so that's why I described a generic example. Whatever the event is I need to know how many people have had that event.

Comment: There is an online example with 3 parts : inputs, desired output, actual method (hope it works) : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9fd5a7a11cd8778dcd6c695f5bc73aab

Comment: you still haven't answered why you have `event_1` and `event_2` in the output - why not just `event` then pivot the result? What are you actually trying to determine from the desired result?

Comment: My desired output is structured that way because it is then exported to a CSV file and imported to a dashboard, and this dashboard only take files with that structure (whether there is one, two or more events by date).

Comment: But actually I can simplify the example with only one event to report. For example if we track positive results from breast cancer screening. We are interested in how many people were tested positive at a given date, how old they were at that date, and the total of people tested positive since the beginning of the program. I made a **new online example** [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6c29aa2345ae403b8868065987043cf6) (I added a third person). I can also edit the example in the question if need be. My problem is more about how to handle changing age group.